# sbt integration tests returning exit code 0 when tests fail

Tags: scala, unit-testing, sbt, integration-testing, exit-code

I am using sbt 0.13.9 (and previously 0.13.8) and Scala 2.11.6.

When running integration tests for my project, sbt always returns "success" with exit code 0 even when it acknowledges test failures. The integration test configuration and settings are the stock ones from sbt (see build.sbt below).

Notice how the failure does not print out a "Failed tests:" section unlike the unit test failure.

[image: Picture of integration test failing with sbt succeeding]

This is odd compared to the unit tests, which do correctly trigger sbt to return an exit code of 1.

[image: Picture of unit test failing with sbt also failing]

With both my unit and integration tests, I had to enable forking to avoid some classloader issues due to dynamically loading a Java library. If forking was the problem, I would assume that I would see the issue with unit tests as well.

My integration tests do involve starting external processes, which I don't know if that affects the results from sbt or not.

The project in question can be found here: https://github.com/chipsenkbeil/scala-debugger

The project's build.sbt is as follows:

```
//
// DEBUGGER API PROJECT CONFIGURATION
//
lazy val scalaDebuggerApi = project
  .in(file("scala-debugger-api"))
  .configs(IntegrationTest)
  .settings(Common.settings: _*)
  .settings(Defaults.itSettings: _*)
  .settings(Seq(
    name := "scala-debugger-api",

    // NOTE: Fork needed to avoid mixing in sbt classloader, which is causing
    //       LinkageError to be thrown for JDI-based classes
    fork in Test := true,
    fork in IntegrationTest := true,

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.5",
      "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-log4j12" % "1.7.5" % "test,it",
      "log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.17" % "test,it",
      "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.1" % "test,it",
      "org.scalamock" %% "scalamock-scalatest-support" % "3.2.1" % "test,it"
    ),
    // JDK Dependency (just for sbt, must exist on classpath for execution,
    // cannot be redistributed)
    internalDependencyClasspath in Compile +=
      { Attributed.blank(Build.JavaTools) },
    internalDependencyClasspath in Runtime +=
      { Attributed.blank(Build.JavaTools) },
    internalDependencyClasspath in Test +=
      { Attributed.blank(Build.JavaTools) },
    internalDependencyClasspath in IntegrationTest +=
      { Attributed.blank(Build.JavaTools) }
  ): _*)
  .dependsOn(scalaDebuggerTest % "test->compile;it->compile")

//
// DEBUGGER TEST CODE PROJECT CONFIGURATION
//
lazy val scalaDebuggerTest = project
  .in(file("scala-debugger-test"))
  .settings(Common.settings: _*)
  .settings(
    // Do not publish the test project
    publishArtifact := false,
    publishLocal := {}
  )

//
// MAIN PROJECT CONFIGURATION
//
lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(Common.settings: _*)
  .settings(
    name := "scala-debugger",
    // Do not publish the aggregation project
    publishArtifact := false,
    publishLocal := {}
  ).aggregate(scalaDebuggerApi, scalaDebuggerTest)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you hit an open issue: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1890. It's related to: https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/432.
Try to get the latest version and see if it's at least partially fixed, i.e. when not running in parallel.

Comment: This was my issue. As it turns out, the latest release of scalatest (3.0.0-M9) has the fix in it; so, updating to that version fixed my issue. Thanks!